# iphone - how to mentain the state of UIWebView?

Tags: iphone, uiwebview

i am having a UIWebView showing and HTML page that has some checkboxes, radio buttons. My Application has tabbar controller that switches b/w two controllers. How i can maintain the current state of UIWebView. ( e.g. i have selected a checkbox and i change the tab and go to other ViewController and again come back to UIWebView. the WebView resets itself and goes to the start... i want to maintain the state of UIWebView ( all the checkboxes clicked) .. how i will do that ??

any idea ??

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're loading your web view in viewDidAppear:, or some other method that gets called each time you switch to the tab.  If you load your web view in viewDidLoad:, it will only get loaded once, and will retain its state when you switch tabs.

---

***EDIT***: When I wrote this answer back in 2009, I apparently didn't understand the view controller life cycle as well as I thought I did.  Corey Floyd was right.  The `viewDidLoad:` method can also get called multiple times, because `UIViewController` will unload its view in low memory situations if the view isn't being displayed.  When the user switches back to the view, `viewDidLoad` gets called again to reconstruct the view.

*How embarrassing.*

Comment: True, but add the caveat: If the view controller receives a memory warning while the view is off screen, it will be destroyed and by extension lose it's state.

Answer (score 0):

I have an idea that might help:

- to get the status from your app to the webpage, give the variables' values as request parameters with the called URL and let the webpage handle them and view the form elements accordingly.
- to get the status from the webpage back to your app, let the webpage be refreshed each time any of its element is updated, and with the new URL give the new values of the changed elements. Back to your app, you can implement the UIWebViewDelegate and inside the method WebViewDidFinishLoad (or WebViewDidStartLoad as you prefer) use the webView.request.URL to parse the GET parameters and update your app accordingly.

hope this will help.